# Why does this program raise "TypeError ">" not supported between instances of "int" and "None type"" for all years entered,except 2000?

Tags: error-handling

`enter code here`
def is_year_leap(year):
if year < 1582:
return False
elif year % 4 != 0:
return False
elif year % 100 != 0:
return True
elif year % 400 != 0:
return False
else:
return True

def days_in_month(year, month):
days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
if is_year_leap(year):
if month == 2:
return 29
return days[month - 1]

def day_of_year(year, month, day):
if year < 1592:
return None
if month > 12 or month < 1:
return None
if day > days_in_month(year, month) or day < 1:
return None
totalDays = day
month = month - 1
while month > 0:
totalDays += days_in_month(year,month)
month -= 1
return totalDays

print(day_of_year(2000, 12, 31))